# No rejoin-stack.sh script in my setup

Tags: openstack-nova, devstack

I've installed the "all-in-one" setup of DevStack.

But when I rebooted my system nothings works, and I lose all my already-created instances, images, configs, ...

I've found that I need to use the script **rejoin-stack.sh** but in my setup doesn't exists.

Please, any suggestions could help me, I'm blocked by the same problem since 1 week !

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned elsewhere here, rejoin-stack.sh was recently removed.  It was barely maintained and did not work for a lot of use cases, plus it encouraged an overall use case that DevStack is not intended to support, that of restoring a running stack after a reboot.  You will need to run stack.sh and create a new cloud.  Put the things that you always want done (like adding your public key, creating special flavors, etc) into local.sh and they will be done at the end of stack.sh.

DevStack is not meant and should not be used for running a cloud.  If that is your need, please investigate one of the many alternatives that are designed and tested for cloud operation, including upgrades.

Comment: Thanks @DeanTroyer for your helpful explanations, could you suggest me an OpenSource or Free alternative that is designed and tested for cloud operation, like my case study.

Comment: That sounds like you are doing something that is not development or testing of OpenStack?  DevStack is NOT meant to be used for ongoing cloud operation, and requiring that instances be recovered after a host reboot falls into that category.  There are many alternatives for operating OpenStack clouds, start with any of the major Linux distros, they all have packages and implementation setups.

Comment: I want to set a cloud VM in Ubuntu on my laptop, and configure it with java,  application server, ... and deploy and test some web services on it. What means, all configs and installed tools in my VM will be kept configured after rebooting my laptop or VMWare. I don't know which cloud solution should i use ?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, no rejoin-stack.sh 
I use ./stack.sh every time.

Comment: But how do you keep the state of instances, VMs, ... after rebooting your machine ? Is this an issue in DevStack or a normal lack ?

Answer (score 2):

According to this [git commit](https://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack-dev/devstack/commit/?id=9ba49cd82631ada84b8458b370ac535985d57725) on openstack-dev it was intentionally removed. If somebody still need it it can be manually recreated from the above commit link.

Comment: Thanks @Alex for your reply. I’ve checked the git commit, I ’ven’t found any proposed alternative official solution to deal with keeping (Instances, VMs, Configs, …) state back after rebooting DevStack ! Are they working on it, or is there another official solution ?

Answer (score 1):

@Alex is right, the script can be recreated by switching to the kilo branch.

Here is the script >>

```html
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This script rejoins an existing screen, or re-creates a
# screen session from a previous run of stack.sh.

TOP_DIR=`dirname $0`

# Import common functions in case the localrc (loaded via stackrc)
# uses them.
source $TOP_DIR/functions

source $TOP_DIR/stackrc

# if screenrc exists, run screen
if [[ -e $TOP_DIR/stack-screenrc ]]; then
    if screen -ls | egrep -q "[0-9].stack"; then
        echo "Attaching to already started screen session.."
        exec screen -r stack
    fi
    exec screen -c $TOP_DIR/stack-screenrc
fi

echo "Couldn't find $TOP_DIR/stack-screenrc file; have you run stack.sh yet?"
exit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

From liberty release, .rejoin-stack.sh was removed by the openstack community, to get the screen you can execute the below command:

```
screen -c "your-screens-file-name"
```

ex: `screen -c stack-screenrc`

stack-screenrc is the screen name located under devstack directory.

Answer (score -4):

It seems rejoin-stack.sh is missing. It is a bug.

Comment: It is not a bug as bentioned it above.