# Openstack horizon issues not starting up

Tags: openstack-horizon

I have installed a openstack sigle mode in my vm, but when I restart the vm I cant log in to the horizon web page.

Any ideas?

thanks.

Comment: Try posting your error message

Comment: Hello I dont get any error , just when I open the web unable to connect is the only thing I get. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using devstack, right? When you restart your VM, some of devstack services are failing, so Horizon cannot connect to these services. 
You should go to the screen sessions and go through all windows to restart all services.

Now so long ago you were able to run ./rejoin_stack.sh, but is was removed because it does not do this job right (look like).

So I believe it would be better for you to run ./unstack.sh and stack.sh again. 
As said in the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36268822/no-rejoin-stack-sh-script-in-my-setup)

> DevStack is not meant and should not be used for running a cloud.