# Openstack: Horizon - "Unable to retrieve usage information" error after VM Shutdown

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-horizon

I have setup Openstack (Newton) with Nova (Compute) on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS Desktop as a virtual machine guest (Oracle VM VirtualBox ver.5.1.8) on Windows 10 host.

The installation was successful and could access the Horizon after the login process via http://192.168.56.102/dashboard/ (from the Host) as shown in the figure below. (Can also access via http://10.0.2.15/dashboard/ from the Guest but not shown here)

[image]

When the VM was shut down and later switched on again, the access to Openstack using Horizon’s dashboard was lost. “Error: Unable to retrieve usage information” is shown on the dashboard (as in the top right position of the figure below). This issue is a hard problem and could be replicated all the time.

[image]

The below is the snipped of error shown in /var/log/apache2/horizon_error.log file when Computer->Overview option was selected from the Horizon’s dashboard after the login process (that produces Figure 2 above).

```
2016-12-02 13:03:08.786092 Recoverable error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='10.0.2.15', port=8774): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2.1/extensions (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f3436ebeb10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
2016-12-02 13:03:08.804729 DEBUG:keystoneauth.session:REQ: curl -g -i -X GET http://10.0.2.15/identity/v3/users/9af3721f2d8e41cc9342b9941bafc5d1/projects -H "User-Agent: python-keystoneclient" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: {SHA1}67ffd6b14a7e8891ae7cc8b29a639b81822c7b45"
2016-12-02 13:03:08.935723 DEBUG:keystoneauth.session:RESP: [200] Date: Fri, 02 Dec 2016 13:03:08 GMT Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Vary: X-Auth-Token x-openstack-request-id: req-fa398fe1-c5c9-4ce6-986b-cec266278f04 Content-Length: 966 Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100 Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Type: application/json 
2016-12-02 13:03:08.935791 RESP BODY: {"links": {"self": "http://10.0.2.15/identity/v3/users/9af3721f2d8e41cc9342b9941bafc5d1/projects", "previous": null, "next": null}, "projects": [{"is_domain": false, "description": "Bootstrap project for initializing the cloud.", "links": {"self": "http://10.0.2.15/identity/v3/projects/4350966521b54001aeb666b6e55b7deb"}, "enabled": true, "id": "4350966521b54001aeb666b6e55b7deb", "parent_id": "default", "domain_id": "default", "name": "admin"}, {"is_domain": false, "description": "", "links": {"self": "http://10.0.2.15/identity/v3/projects/43dba94541ba4e8e83d5528038346ea9"}, "enabled": true, "id": "43dba94541ba4e8e83d5528038346ea9", "parent_id": "default", "domain_id": "default", "name": "demo"}, {"is_domain": false, "description": "", "links": {"self": "http://10.0.2.15/identity/v3/projects/be3ee2f8cb074628ac24c8be6e4c7160"}, "enabled": true, "id": "be3ee2f8cb074628ac24c8be6e4c7160", "parent_id": "default", "domain_id": "default", "name": "alt_demo"}]}
2016-12-02 13:03:08.935809 
2016-12-02 13:03:09.018515 Call to list enabled services failed. This is likely due to a problem communicating with the Neutron endpoint. Load Balancers panel will not be displayed.
2016-12-02 13:03:09.024775 Call to list enabled services failed. This is likely due to a problem communicating with the Neutron endpoint. Firewalls panel will not be displayed.
2016-12-02 13:03:09.029002 Call to list enabled services failed. This is likely due to a problem communicating with the Neutron endpoint. VPN panel will not be displayed.
2016-12-02 13:03:09.035255 Call to list supported extensions failed. This is likely due to a problem communicating with the Nova endpoint. Host Aggregates panel will not be displayed
```

As the error about indicated problem in communicating with the endpoint. Verified if the endpoint for the services is ok in the VM, unfortunately it is not.

```
svanan@svanan:~/devstack$ openstack endpoint list
Password: 
Missing parameter(s): 
Set a username with --os-username, OS_USERNAME, or auth.username
Set an authentication URL, with --os-auth-url, OS_AUTH_URL or auth.auth_url
```

The below is the original output in the VM when before it was shutdown.

```
svanan@svanan:~/devstack$ openstack endpoint list
+----------------------------------+-----------+--------------+----------------+---------+-----------+-----------------------------------------+
| ID                               | Region    | Service Name | Service Type   | Enabled | Interface | URL                                     |
+----------------------------------+-----------+--------------+----------------+---------+-----------+-----------------------------------------+
| 07480eca2071416c8dec30bafa95ff8f | RegionOne | neutron      | network        | True    | admin     | http://10.0.2.15:9696/                  |
| 0aa32dc14c194561816b6d1b60d04404 | RegionOne | glance       | image          | True    | admin     | http://10.0.2.15:9292                   |
| 0e5365a8ab3744c780feb25ecffc2c93 | RegionOne | keystone     | identity       | True    | internal  | http://10.0.2.15/identity               |
| 15d8608b021f42e2a3b0402889a9064f | RegionOne | neutron      | network        | True    | public    | http://10.0.2.15:9696/                  |
| 289a99bb83e846b2bfc5eabfb800d86d | RegionOne | glance       | image          | True    | internal  | http://10.0.2.15:9292                   |
| 41397886443d44b7b6d857fccb34d55d | RegionOne | neutron      | network        | True    | internal  | http://10.0.2.15:9696/                  |
| 4458eed550ae44479feca25f9bec96ce | RegionOne | nova_legacy  | compute_legacy | True    | public    | http://10.0.2.15:8774/v2/$(project_id)s |
| 51be7c90e6c4437fbb75c3a40857774f | RegionOne | keystone     | identity       | True    | public    | http://10.0.2.15/identity               |
| 7526c5a7e5084a07b1d1c7affe261ae4 | RegionOne | nova_legacy  | compute_legacy | True    | admin     | http://10.0.2.15:8774/v2/$(project_id)s |
| 7c1e026c1c2d4f0b9dfdfe15860d6c5b | RegionOne | keystone     | identity       | True    | admin     | http://10.0.2.15/identity_v2_admin      |
| 8641d88381fc499688162e8bcde5456c | RegionOne | cinderv2     | volumev2       | True    | internal  | http://10.0.2.15:8776/v2/$(project_id)s |
| 8a194a2954a943568ccaf8bce5eb9400 | RegionOne | cinder       | volume         | True    | internal  | http://10.0.2.15:8776/v1/$(project_id)s |
| 8c0b4d932da34c5990e43c0877146819 | RegionOne | nova         | compute        | True    | admin     | http://10.0.2.15:8774/v2.1              |
| 94e8cae799954ba09abcd3b31b1c926e | RegionOne | nova         | compute        | True    | public    | http://10.0.2.15:8774/v2.1              |
| a1527968e91d4df9b98fe09039e80bed | RegionOne | cinderv2     | volumev2       | True    | public    | http://10.0.2.15:8776/v2/$(project_id)s |
| a3e47c8f82d546c8917a8223b8b81a74 | RegionOne | cinderv3     | volumev3       | True    | internal  | http://10.0.2.15:8776/v3/$(project_id)s |
| b39a19918016462db99cf1de151fc870 | RegionOne | cinderv3     | volumev3       | True    | public    | http://10.0.2.15:8776/v3/$(project_id)s |
| d17514aa0eec4752848df9599dd8cd00 | RegionOne | cinder       | volume         | True    | admin     | http://10.0.2.15:8776/v1/$(project_id)s |
| db570fe7343b461a95cdd4179e1b28d9 | RegionOne | glance       | image          | True    | public    | http://10.0.2.15:9292                   |
| eb4aa71c03b0418eadfed00715744b07 | RegionOne | cinderv3     | volumev3       | True    | admin     | http://10.0.2.15:8776/v3/$(project_id)s |
| ee474205e562411abc1842dc9bccbb5d | RegionOne | nova_legacy  | compute_legacy | True    | internal  | http://10.0.2.15:8774/v2/$(project_id)s |
| f383e0696ee647f79f6fd3a3d7ac5dff | RegionOne | cinder       | volume         | True    | public    | http://10.0.2.15:8776/v1/$(project_id)s |
| f4239a1f86144d8dab3ed94237d7c10f | RegionOne | cinderv2     | volumev2       | True    | admin     | http://10.0.2.15:8776/v2/$(project_id)s |
| fe679fcbc79e4664b7897a381e90dd78 | RegionOne | nova         | compute        | True    | internal  | http://10.0.2.15:8774/v2.1              |
+----------------------------------+-----------+--------------+----------------+---------+-----------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Verified ifconfig at VM, it has the enp0s3, enp0s8, lo, virbr0  interfaces configured except the br-ex which was there before the shutdown as below:

```
br-ex     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1a:ba:3a:4a:d5:4f  
          inet addr:172.24.4.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::18ba:3aff:fe4a:d54f/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2001:db8::2/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:79 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:776 (776.0 B)  TX bytes:10328 (10.3 KB)
```

Not sure if the absense of this bridge (br-ex) could be the cause Horizon (from the Host) could not connect with the services in the Guest. Tried to configure statically in etc/network/interfaces as below to get the same above br-ex output.

```
auto br-ex
  iface br-ex inet static
  hwaddress 1a:ba:3a:4a:d5:4f
  address 172.24.4.1
  broadcast 0.0.0.0
  netmask 255.255.255.0

  iface br-ex inet6 static
  pre-up modprobe ipv6
  address 2001:db8::2
  netmask 64
```

The br-ex output I got after

```
svanan@svanan:~$ sudo systemctl restart networking
svanan@svanan:~$ ifconfig

br-ex     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7a:07:1d:1d:1a:40  
          inet addr:172.24.4.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::18ba:3aff:fe4a:d54f/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2001:db8::2/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:126 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:19334 (19.3 KB)
```

As can be seen above I am unable to configure HWaddr to 1a:ba:3a:4a:d5:4f instead 7a:07:1d:1d:1a:40 showing up.

**Questions:**

1. Could the absense of br-ex after the VM shutdown and switched on sequence could be the reason Horizon’s failure to retrieve the information from its services.
2. How to statically set the HWaddr to 1a:ba:3a:4a:d5:4f for br-ex? The syntax hwaddress 1a:ba:3a:4a:d5:4f does not seem to work.
3. If you faces similar problem, can you share how did you solve it.
4. Is it true, one need to run ./unstack.sh and ./stack.sh ( ./rejoin-stack.sh has been depreciated in Newton) everytime a VM is restarted as mentioned in [No rejoin-stack.sh script in my setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36268822/no-rejoin-stack-sh-script-in-my-setup) .This approach takes very long time as shown below,

   =========================

   DevStack Component Timing

   =========================

   Total runtime         1777

Hope you can assist to guide me in this. Thanks.

Saravanan Kandasamy

Comment: Hey bro! even I've got the same error from last Monday. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Ashish -- If you are using the same setup as mine. Rather than "Power off the machine" option to shut down the VM, choose "Save the machine state" instead. It preserves the connection. This work around is ok for me at least for now as I am now working on establishing VLANs using Neutron. If you shut down the VM -- ./unstack.sh && ./stack.sh is what you have to do now. I have done profiling found the time taken to reestablish the services is lesser (1777 runtime) than when you first installed (2788 runtime).

Comment: Ashish - Read another work around at the second half of http://www.linuxtechi.com/multiple-node-openstack-liberty-installation-on-centos-7-x/ have not spend time to understand it and see how it applies for my case

Comment: I did `Save the machine state`. But still I get the error. BTW thanks for the link. This problem started when I updated to Newton. everything was fine with Mitaka. Now i don;t understand how to revert back to mitaka coz when I install the repository it comes with the latest version!!

Comment: Ashish - a) I also faced the same problem when I shift to another wireless network, say from Office 1 to Office 2. If used at the same place "Save the machine state" works for me. b) Do not take the link I sent on face value. It requires analysis. The approach might work. If the open-rc you are using pointing to different auth_uri for example in cinder.conf. It need to point to the right address. In my case it has to be from http://10.0.2.15/identity to http://10.0.2.15/identity/v3 I think. Need some test to be sure.

Comment: Yup! How can I miss the cinder.conf. Lol.;) Thanx for the suggestion man.